# What is NOT supported in TFS 2013 Git mode from what is there for TFVC?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

Recently I realized the fact that not all functionality available for TFVC is supported for Git-mode projects in TFS 2013. This has been indirectly proved by the [blog post of Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx), saying:

> ...we are fully integrating Git into the TFS ALM workflows – work item
>   tracking, build automation, reporting, code review, and more. Not all
>   of that integration is complete yet but we’ll be fleshing it out
>   through the 2013 Updates and, when we are done, we should have full
>   parity on ALM integration capabilities between Team Foundation Version
>   Control and Git Version Control.

The following are a couple of those "not supported in Git mode" things I faced with:

- Gated-checkins
- Code review

The concept of the shelvelets also doesn't seem relevant for Git. Taking into account that "My Work" area for TFVC fully relies on shelvelets, it will obviously not be available for Git mode.

What are other areas available for TFVC, but not implemented (yet) for Git mode? Do any workarounds exist for each?

Comment: I'm not sure this question will stay relevant. In six months answer will probably be horribly out of date.

Comment: @AndrewClear that's why you can update your answers. Updateing also bumps the question and it is likely to get more views which then may result in upvotes for non-outdated answers. That should be enough motivation for anyone who knows an answer.

Comment: Code review feature will be available in TFS 2015 (and MSVS 2015): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-visual-studio-2015-preview-availability.aspx

Comment: @ManushinIgor I don't see code review functionality listed in that link for TFS 2015.  I do see some more Git+TFS features, but not the code review that I'm used to for TFSVC.

Eeek. Scratch that. Maybe they're in the form of "pull requests" now.???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TFS documentation has a part about [details on the differences between TFVC and Git](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181368.aspx#tfvc_or_git_details).
There is a lot of details, but gated-checkins, "My Work", code review and Source control explorer are the only major features that are not yet supported (and relevant with Git).

There are 2 others features in the file editor which were missing before Visual Studio [Update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779) : CodeLens inline history and history annotation.

Code Review option seems to show up in [Update 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/09/03/vs-amp-tfs-2013-update-4-ctp-1-is-available.aspx) with pull requests feature.

Comment: The biggest one for us is that Check-in Policies are not yet supported with Git; hopefully soon though.

Answer (score 3):

Because branches are cheap in Git I can imagine Code Reviews and Gated Check-in will make use of that. Redirect a push to a temporary server side branch and fast-forward merge when the build succeeds, or something like that.

Update:
Brian Harry mentions a little bit about in an IMA session he did on reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/17paji/iam_brian_harry_microsoft_technical_fellow_in/c87na4j