# Understanding TFS from a Git background; specifically how branching differs in TFS

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

I have come from a Git background, and happily used Git for source control for a few years. I am now trying to work on a TFS project, and I am specifically trying to create a branch, similar to how you would create a branch in Git. I have found many resources for migrating or moving to Git for people familar with TFS, but none for the other way around. I am to understand that branches are different in TFS and that you cannot branch the entire repository but instead folders within the repository. I am confused as to why this is, can someone explain to me what the different approach is I should be using in TFS? Perhaps I need to change my view on source control in order to work effectively as part of the TFS team? Are there any resources out there for someone looking to move from Git to TFS (instead of TFS to Git which there seem to be lots for)?

The question I am really looking for the answer for is simply how to create a branch in TFS, but I think there might be some other fundamental TFS concepts I need to understand before I can answer this question.

Many Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, Git support was added to TFS 2013 which may or may not help your situation. See this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013.aspx) and this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668667/what-is-not-supported-in-tfs-2013-git-mode-from-what-is-there-for-tfvc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the conceptual difference you're struggling with is that TFS Source Code Repositories are usually scoped larger than Git repositories.  There may be many teams, developing many applications all working out of the same TFS Team Project.  So if a team wants to branch just their application, they don't want to branch the whole repo, they just want to branch their folder that contains their application code.

In the Git world you would probably have many different repo's for each/team application.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was doing wrong, I was trying to branch at the root level when I should have been trying to branch at the folder level.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your basic question of how to create a branch in TFS.
1. Open Source Explorer in Visual Studio
2. Right click on the directory at the level you want to branch from
3. Navigate to "Branching and Merging" -> Branch
4. Define your target, version, etc in the Branch box
5. Hit Ok.

For the concepts and practices piece check, I suggest you check out the [ALM rangers guide](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) to branching and merging in TFS
https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/